# How much CPU & memory to allocate to a ECS task to fully utilise EC2 instance (1 task per instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am running the ECS Cluster using EC2 t4g.micro. This has 2VPCPU and 1GB Memory.

As these tasks will be running in daemon mode (i.e. 1 task per an instance), how much memory and CPU units should I allocate in the task definition so it can fully take advantage of the resources available in the EC2 instance?

I could max the resources out (i.e. 2048 CPU unit and 1024MB memory for the task), but I am unsure if I should reserve some resources for the OS and Docker. If so, how much CPU or memory should I reserve? Is there a way to just fully allocate all the resources available automatically?

*NOTE: If I run a t4g.micro EC2 instance without any tasks running on it, it says 2048 CPU units and 916MB available.*

*UPDATE: I noticed CPU units can be left empty for the task definition. However this still leaves the issue of memory.*

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) says both CPU and Memory settings are optional when running your tasks on EC2:

> When you register a task definition, you can specify the total CPU and memory used for the task. This is separate from the cpu and memory values at the container definition level. For tasks that are hosted on Amazon EC2 instances, these fields are optional.

Comment: On experimentation it looks like I need either task memory, container soft memory limit, or container hard memory limit. I need to specify at least one.

Comment: Specifying container soft memory limit to something close to your EC2 instance's memory should be fine, and since it's a soft limit, it can still use more.